# Unity. Closing the android phone screen during the ad display process causes a black screen to appear

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement unity ads for the first time in an android game. Everything seems to be working properly except for one thing. When the ShowAd method is called
it takes 2 seconds for the advertisement to be actually displayed, during which time if you turn off and open the phone screen, the game stops, superimposing a black screen on the screen. I think what really happens is that the ad starts in the background until the application loses its focus, and when I reopen the phone the ad closes automatically leaving only the black screen. I thought that to avoid this, I should reload the application based on a check in onapplicationfocus function, such as: if the user pressed the lock button on the phone, if the screen is closed, or simply a check if the application is lost focus due to the ad or another event. Another solution would be to configure the application to run in the background somehow, but I did not manage to apply any of the above. Does anyone know how to apply one of the above? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't there like a callback from Unity Ads telling you whether the ad was displayed properly?

Comment: there is such a callback, but in this case the application crashes in an attempt to display an advertisement, and as the game has no focus at that moment, I can not do anything in the code in this regard.

Comment: Well, if your game crashes, you can't do anything except hope for the user to relaunch it. Btw, have you submitted a bug report to Unity? They might be able to fix it.

Comment: I don't think it crashed and I'm trying to explain why I think so. If you display an ad and the user puts the application on standby and returns to it, the ad disappears, this is based on their policy of not forcing users to watch an ad if they do not want it. During the advertisement, the application is practically stopped until the advertisement is finished displaying. So during the process of displaying the advertisement which usually lasts 2 seconds, if you turn off the phone, a black screen appears, the application stops but the advertisement does not appear.

Comment: But if you apply the standby thing explained above, the game resumes. I guess the last thing left to do is report this. Thanks for your time!